# Setting custom variable to a cons

Tags: defcustom

I have the following user customisation declaration.

```
(defgroup px-initial-frame nil
  "Customisation group for position of initial frame."
  :group 'convenience)

(defcustom px-frame-pos (cons 8 8)
  "Position of initial frame."
  :type 'sexp
  :group 'px-initial-frame)
```

At some point I want to save some computed values.  I aw using

```
(custom-declare-variable 'px-frame-pos (cons lft top))
```

Which is reporting

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (3 . 3) 2)
  custom-declare-variable(typex-frame-pos (1270 . 1223))
```

What is going wrong and how can this problem get fixed?

Comment: In `custom-declare-variable` you just miss the doc string. That is the mismatch in the number of arguments. Furthermore, you need the keyword arguments for `:type` and the `:group`.

Comment: Right, I have to add a documentation string. Having already defined a `defcustom`, what is the appropriate command to change the value of a `defcustom`.  I used `custom-declare-variable` but perhaps this declares the `defcustom` variable a second time.